# FOSS alternative to iMacros for Firefox Quantum?

Tags: imacros, firefox-quantum

I hope this is the right SE forum for this... I considered SuperUser, but OTOH iMacros scripts do distinctly involve programming.

I'm currently stuck with Firefox 55 because FF 57 ("Quantum") notoriously broke various add-ons, including iMacros as it was (v. 9).

I've just visited the iMacros site to check out the present situation... and I find that if you want to run an .iim script in FF Quantum+, using iMacros 10, it appears that you have to pay for a licence: https://imacros.net/store/compare-versions/.  Strangely, IE appears to be exempted from this restriction. Odd, to say the least.

Fine, I don't mind paying a bit for someone's work for an unlimited, future-proof licence... so I visit the payment page to find that the cost is £107! ($140 or so)! This appears foolish, as it will presumably encourage FF devotees who want to automate some of their browsing activity to seek FOSS alternatives. Maybe even develop their own.

Has anyone been similarly stymied by FF Quantum, and found a credible FOSS alternative to iMacros (specifically for Quantum)?  There are various "alternative to" sites but I haven't found any proper reviews of how serviceable Selenium might be, for example.

***later***
Of course another obvious alternative, for simple jobs which lend themselves to this, is our old friend [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) (or conceivably [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey/wiki/Beginners-Guide) in Linux).  Some scripts of mine will lend themselves to this, no doubt => even less incentive (if that's possible) to shell out a totally ridiculous sum of money.

Comment: what is imacros